# SVG path doesn't seem to orientate itself correctly

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm attempting to generate a path around 2 circles that should follow them as I move them around. I've based this on an example that I found and built a prototype of what I'm expecting to achieve [example](http://tributary.io/inlet/f33a0503ea923d090019)

[image]

I've started including this in my application, but for some reason I can't seem to get the green path to draw around the correct positions, and I can't figure out why.

I've put together a code example to illustrate:

```js
function generatePath(planet, moon, join) {

    function distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        var a = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1);
        var b = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1);
        return Math.sqrt(a + b);
    };
    
    function circleYFromX(circle, x) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.r, 2) - Math.pow(x - circle.x, 2));
    };
    
     function calculateAngle(origin, point) {
        var tan = (point.y - origin.y) / (point.x - origin.x);
        var angle = Math.atan(tan) / Math.PI * 180 + 90;
        if (point.x < origin.x) angle += 180;
        return angle;
    };
    
    // Work out the distance between the moon and planet
    var distance = distanceBetween(planet.x, planet.y, moon.x, moon.y);
    var originDistance = planet.r - moon.r;
    var distanceDiff = distance - originDistance;
    if (distanceDiff < 1) {
        distanceDiff = 1;
    }

    console.log(distance);
    console.log(planet.r);
    console.log(moon.r);
    console.log(join.r);
    console.log(planet.r + moon.r + 2 * join.r);
    
    // Determine if the moon has moved out of the planet's gravitational pull
    if (distance > 2 * join.r + planet.r + moon.r) {
        return;
    }

    moon.h = 0;
    moon.k = 0 - planet.r + moon.r - distanceDiff;

    var triangleA = planet.r + join.r; // Side planet
    var triangleB = moon.r + join.r; // Side moon
    var triangleC = Math.abs(moon.k - 0); // Side c
    var triangleP = (triangleA + triangleB + triangleC) / 2; // Triangle half perimeter
    var triangleArea = Math.sqrt(triangleP * (triangleP - triangleA) * (triangleP - triangleB) * (triangleP - triangleC)); // Triangle area
    var triangleH;
    var triangleD;

    if (triangleC >= triangleA) {
        var triangleH = 2 * triangleArea / triangleC; // Triangle height
        var triangleD = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(triangleA, 2) - Math.pow(triangleH, 2)); // Big circle bisection of triangleC
    } else {
        var triangleH = 2 * triangleArea / triangleA; // Triangle height
        var triangleD = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(triangleC, 2) - Math.pow(triangleH, 2)); // Small circle bisection of triangleA
    }

    planet.tan = triangleH / triangleD;
    planet.angle = Math.atan(planet.tan);
    planet.sin = Math.sin(planet.angle);
    planet.intersectX = planet.sin * planet.r;
    planet.cos = Math.cos(planet.angle);
    planet.intersectY = planet.cos * planet.r;

    join.x = 0 + planet.sin * (planet.r + join.r);
    join.y = 0 - planet.cos * (planet.r + join.r);

    var coord1 = {
        x: -planet.intersectX,
        y: -planet.intersectY
    };
    var coord2 = {
        x: planet.intersectX,
        y: -planet.intersectY
    }
    moon.tan = (moon.k - join.y) / (moon.h - join.x);
    moon.angle = Math.atan(moon.tan);
    moon.intersectX = join.x - Math.cos(moon.angle) * (join.r);
    moon.intersectY = join.y - Math.sin(moon.angle) * (join.r);
    
    // If we have any bad values then just return no path
    if (isNaN(coord1.x) || isNaN(coord1.y) || isNaN(coord2.x) || isNaN(coord2.y)) {
        return;
    }

    var pathD = "M " + coord1.x + " " + coord1.y + " A " + planet.r + " " + planet.r + " 0 1 0 " + coord2.x + " " + coord2.y;
    if (join.x - join.r <= 0 && moon.k < join.y) {
        var crossOverY = circleYFromX(join, 0);
        pathD += "A " + join.r + " " + join.r + " 0 0 1 0 " + (join.y + crossOverY);
        pathD += "m 0 -" + (crossOverY * 2);
    }

    pathD += "A " + join.r + " " + join.r + " 0 0 1 " + moon.intersectX + " " + moon.intersectY;
    var largeArcFlag = 1;
    if (join.y < moon.k) {
        largeArcFlag = 0;
    }

    pathD += "a " + moon.r + " " + moon.r + " 0 " + largeArcFlag + " 0 " + (moon.intersectX * -2) + " 0";
    if (join.x - join.r <= 0 && moon.k < join.y) {
        pathD += "A " + join.r + " " + join.r + " 0 0 1 0 " + (join.y - crossOverY);
        pathD += "m 0 " + (crossOverY * 2);
    }

    pathD += "A " + join.r + " " + join.r + " 0 0 1 " + coord1.x + " " + coord1.y;
    pathD += "A " + join.r + " " + join.r + " 0 0 1 " + coord1.x + " " + coord1.y;
    return pathD;
};

var container = d3.select(".planet");
var moon = d3.select(".moon");
var tempPlanet = { x: -181.77581967381693, y: -144.9613789321555, r: 152 };
var tempMoon = { x: 0, y: 0, r: 32 };
var link = { r: 7.9 };

var pathD = generatePath(tempPlanet, tempMoon, { r: 31 });
if (pathD) {
                moon.append("path")
                        .attr("d", pathD)
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [-181.77581967381693, 144.9613789321555] + ")")
                        .attr("class", "gravity")
                        .style("fill", "none")
                        .style("stroke", "red")
                        .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1680" height="523">
    <g width="1680" height="523">
        <g class="galaxy-main" width="1680" height="523">
            <g class="planet selected" transform="translate(341,300) scale(0.5,0.5)">
                <circle r="150" style="fill: rgb(72, 119, 159); stroke-dasharray: 944.477796076938px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px; stroke-width: 8px; stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
                <g class="moon" transform="translate(181.77581967381693,-144.96137893215555)">
                    <circle r="30" class="moon-circle" id="3" style="fill: rgb(72, 119, 159);"></circle>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Instead of drawing a green fill I'm currently drawing a red outline. What you should be able to see is that the red outline correctly surrounds the larger circle (planet) but goes vertically up instead of around the smaller circle (moon).

[image]

It appears as thought we're just missing a rotation, but the original prototype I built doesn't **know** about a rotation, just the center of each circle. In this case this should be really simple:

**Moon**

```
var tempMoon = { x: 0, y: 0, r: 32 };
```

Always located at (0, 0) as this circle sits in the center of the group which the path will be appended to

**Planet**

```
var tempPlanet = { x: -181.77581967381693, y: -144.9613789321555, r: 152 };
```

The planet is at the center of the group, which also contains the moon group. Therefore it's location is always just an inverse translation which positions the group containing the moon

I believe the locations are correct (I've tried adding circles on the moon layer to confirm they are in the correct place - which they are). I feel that this must be somehow down to the groups but I still can't pinpoint why this isn't rendering with the correct orientation.

Comment: At a quick glance, one thing I notice is that the example draws the path and rotates it to envelope the "moon".  You do not do this rotation.  Adding it in [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EvVFXQZugiwblxHO7i0M?p=preview) improves your problem but the angle seems off by radius of moon.

Comment: @Mark: You know what, I've been stupid. You're right it does translate it and I'd just missed that somehow. That's an interesting first step though, I might be able to work out why it's out by that offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that I was missing a `translate` and `rotate` in the code toward the end that I'd missed previously for some reason. Including this in made it work as expected.